# Remove an extra output from subprocess module in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to execute commands using the subprocess module on windows, but there is an output which is "CompletedProcess(args=['command'], returncode=0)"
How can I remove this output and show only my command output?

My code:

```
import subprocess

command = subprocess.run(['whoami'])

print(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise capture_output & text to print out your output.

```
command = subprocess.run(['whoami'], capture_output=True, text=True)
print(command.stdout)
```

Comment: Or if you just want to display the output to the user, simply `subprocess.check_call(['whoami'])`